# memoir: indentation of unnumbered sections in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

In the following MWE, I only want the chapter titles in the TOC numbered. But using `\setsecnumdepth{chapter}` messes up indentation of long section headings.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}


\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
  mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
  Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\sometext}

\section{\sometext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\cftsetindents` to have the desired indentation; in the example below I used

```
\cftsetindents{section}{2.5em}{0em}
```

but adjust the settings according to your needs.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}
\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\cftsetindents{section}{2.5em}{0em}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
  vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
  mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
  Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\sometext}

\section{\sometext}

\end{document}
```

[image]